# Shell script to fetch sql query data in csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Need to extract the below query data along with header in csv file using shell script.

Below is the query.

```
SELECT SourceIdentifier,SourceFileName,ProfitCentre2,PlantCode,
tax_retur ReturnPeriod,document_number DocumentNumber,TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
Docume,Original,customer_name CustomerName,NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS,PortCode,NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC,(SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat,(SGS+UT)StateUT,Userde FROM arbor.INV_REPO_FINA WHERE UPPER(document_type)='INV' AND UPPER(backout_flag)='VALID' AND new_gst_id_new IS NOT NULL AND new_charges<>0 AND taxable_adj=0
UNION
SELECT SourceIdentifier,SourceFileName,ProfitCentre2,PlantCode,
tax_retur ReturnPeriod,document_number DocumentNumber,TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
Docume,Original,customer_name CustomerName,NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS,PortCode, NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC,(SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat,(SGS+UTG)StateUT,Userde FROM arbor.INV_REPO_FINA WHERE UPPER(document_type)='INV' AND UPPER(backout_flag)='VALID' AND new_gst_id_new IS NOT NULL AND new_charges<>0 AND  taxable_adj<>0
```

Could please let me know if below approach to fetch data using shell script is correct and script is correct.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="output.csv"
sqlplus -s username/password@Oracle_SID << EOF
SPOOL $file

select 'SourceIdentifier','SourceFileName','ProfitCentre2','PlantCode',
'tax_retur ReturnPeriod','document_number DocumentNumber','TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') Docume','Original','customer_name CustomerName','NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS','PortCode','NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC','(SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat','(SGS+UT)StateUT','Userde' from dual
Union all
select 'TO_CHAR(SourceIdentifier)','TO_CHAR(SourceFileName)','TO_CHAR(ProfitCentre2)','TO_CHAR(PlantCode)',
'TO_CHAR(tax_retur ReturnPeriod)','TO_CHAR(document_number DocumentNumber)','TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
Docume','TO_CHAR(Original)','TO_CHAR(customer_name CustomerName)','TO_CHAR(NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS)','TO_CHAR(PortCode)','TO_CHAR(NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC)','TO_CHAR((SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat)','TO_CHAR((SGS+UT)StateUT)','TO_CHAR(Userde)' from
(SELECT SourceIdentifier,SourceFileName,ProfitCentre2,PlantCode,
tax_retur ReturnPeriod,document_number DocumentNumber,TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
Docume,Original,customer_name CustomerName,NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS,PortCode,NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC,(SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat,(SGS+UT)StateUT,Userde FROM arbor.INV_REPO_FINA WHERE UPPER(document_type)='INV' AND UPPER(backout_flag)='VALID' AND new_gst_id_new IS NOT NULL AND new_charges<>0 AND taxable_adj=0
UNION
SELECT SourceIdentifier,SourceFileName,ProfitCentre2,PlantCode,
tax_retur ReturnPeriod,document_number DocumentNumber,TO_CHAR(invoice_generation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
Docume,Original,customer_name CustomerName,NVL(sns_pos,new_state_code)POS,PortCode, NEW_HSN_CODE HSNorSAC,(SGSATE+UTGSATE) Stat,(SGS+UTG)StateUT,Userde FROM arbor.INV_REPO_FINA WHERE UPPER(document_type)='INV' AND UPPER(backout_flag)='VALID' AND new_gst_id_new IS NOT NULL AND new_charges<>0 AND  taxable_adj<>0)

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Comment: is your script working ? if not what error you are getting ?

Comment: @ThiruShetty...its not working and also no giving any error and output

Answer (score 1):

In short: the ; is missing from the end of the select statement.

Some unrequested advice:

I think spool will put extra stuff into your file (at least some new lines), a redirect is better, further the first line is not db-related:

```
echo "SourceIdentifier;SourceFileName;ProfitCentre2..." > $file
```

I recommend to generate the csv format right in the select query, later it will be more headache (you can escape there what you want):

```
$query = "select SourceIdentifier || ';' || SourceFileName || ';' || ProfitCentre2 ... ;"
```

So querying the DB (I think capital -S is the right one) plus for the formatting of the records (and maybe you want to format your columns too):

```
sqlplus -S username/password@Oracle_SID >> $file << EOF
set linesize 32767 pagesize 0 heading off
$query
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you.. Will execute and let you know for errors in case any

Answer (score 0):

For me this one is working but one empty line before first query and second query is coming. Empty line remove using awk command

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="A.csv"
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s username/password@Oracle_SID<<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 50000 COLSEP "," LINESIZE 20000 FEEDBACK OFF HEADING off
SPOOL $FILE

select 'TYPE_OF_CALL_V','SWITCH_CALL_TYPE_V','RECORD_TYPE_V','TARF_TYPE_V' from dual;
SELECT TYPE_OF_CALL_V,SWITCH_CALL_TYPE_V,RECORD_TYPE_V,TARF_TYPE_V FROM TABLE;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF

awk 'NF > 0' $FILE  > out.txt
mv out.txt $FILE
```